# ServiceLocator in Sandbox: is anyone experiencing RemotingExceptions?

Tags: sandbox-solution, guidance

I posted an issue on [SP Guidance tracker](http://spg.codeplex.com/workitem/9289) after quite some searching, but I saw several unanswered issues there so I'm trying here as well.

I think I have a very simple Proof Of Concept: a Sandbox 2010 solution, a coded web part asking for a string from a service, a feature receiver registering the service implementation at site level during activation (or install) time.

As soon as I try to get the service instance in web part CreateChildControls, I incur into this *System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Failed to write to an IPC Port: The pipe is being closed*. In a previous - more complex - try I was having the same exception but for a *Tcp channel protocol violation: expecting preamble*,and that was even during feature activation.

From the stack trace, I can see that SPUserCodeApplicationHostAppDomainRef.Execute is looking for a SPResource.GetString, and that causes reflection (?) to kick in with Activator.CreateInstance. From this stems some SPResource_SubsetProxy, which involves some proxy and then an Ipc.IpcClientTransportSink.ProcessMessage follows.

Has anyone met anything like this?

My dev box has Windows 7 64bit, SP Foundation 2010.

**Edit**

Of course all of this does not happen if I try with a Farm solution (and in feature activation I register mapping at site level with properties.Feature.Parent, instead of properties.UserCodeSite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this could be an actual bug.  Did you ever get this resolved?

[MSHotFix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971521)

Comment: Thanks for the info! And no, I did not manage to resolve that. In the end I had to dump ServiceLocator and all that library altogether :(

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I was having this exact problem with a custom sandbox web part I am developing and it was a real pain to solve. I believe this is caused when there is a static reference to a `SPList` or `SPListItem` object.

A simplified version of the class that was causing this error:

```
class SomeClass
{
    private SPList List;
    private SPListItem ListItem;

    private static SomeClass _Instance;
    public static SomeClass Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_Instance == null) {
                _Instance = new SomeClass();
            }
            return _Instance;
        }
    }

    private SomeClass()
    {
        List = SPContext.Current.Web.GetList("/Lists/SomeList");
        ListItem = List.GetItemById(SPContext.Current.ItemId);
        // other initialisation code.
    }
}
```

This worked the very first time I loaded the web part, but after that it always errored out with *System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Failed to write to an IPC Port: The pipe is being closed.*

Then I changed the class to not store any `SPList` or `SPListItem` references:

```
class SomeClass
{
    private SPList List
    {
        get
        {
            return SPContext.Current.Web.GetList("/Lists/SomeList");
        }
    }
    private SPListItem ListItem
    {
        get
        {
            return List.GetItemById(SPContext.Current.ItemId);
        }
    }

    private static SomeClass _Instance;
    public static SomeClass Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_Instance == null) {
                _Instance = new SomeClass();
            }
            return _Instance;
        }
    }

    private SomeClass()
    {
        // other initialisation code.
    }
}
```

Now the web part works every time. Curiously the first version worked on my local dev box, but failed when I installed it on our staging server.

Comment: thanks for feedback. I have no way to try this now. I hope it can be useful for me or someone else the next time!